# How to unit test certificate exchange in Lumen 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, ssl, lumen

I am working on an API authentication project.  Authentication is achieved by adding a client certificate to the https request to the api.  Everything works great when I curl to my api using my client certificate and Lumen actually made it trivial to do.

What is not so trivial is unit testing this.

Does anyone know how to make an HTTPS connection in a unit test?

The callSecure method seems to have disappeared since the last version of lumen.

Assuming the HTTPS connection is made - does anyone know how to easily set the certificate.  I was hoping I could just get the unit test framework to set up the correct $_SERVER superglobal values so I could use a data provider to send several different certificate errors.

I'd also like to mock the models the controller is injected with so I provide known data in my data providers without having to do any database manipulation.

What I do not want to do is write some methods to make an entire curl request using real certificates.

Answer (score 0):

So - apparently this can not be done as simply as I wanted. In order to test the unit of code in question I have had to add a "getter" to return a copy of the $_SERVER array.  In my unit test I then mock the controller object and override the getter to return data I can control.  Then rather than using the call method in the test I just directly call the method I am testing.

It has added complexity in terms of having to do more development within the production code just so I can have some tests - however that additional development time will be well worth it in the future.